# How to Compare Member of Array of Complex Type to a SELECT?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Given a table like this:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╤════════╤═══════════╗
║ message_id                           │ type   │ json_data ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╪════════╪═══════════╣
║ 2c8c86b7-4867-494a-88bf-1e6b17dd121f │ type-a │ {}        ║
╟──────────────────────────────────────┼────────┼───────────╢
║ 767d6fbf-84cf-4baa-9e33-46b15f0c8594 │ type-b │ {}        ║
╟──────────────────────────────────────┼────────┼───────────╢
║ 298dcedb-b51d-4623-89f8-fabec44663c8 │ type-c │ {}        ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╧════════╧═══════════╝
```

and a type like the following:

```
CREATE TYPE public.new_stream_message AS (
  message_id    UUID,
  "type"        VARCHAR(128),
  json_data     VARCHAR,
  json_metadata VARCHAR
);
```

and a function which takes an array of these as one of the parameters.

inside this function I write this array out to a table. If there is a unique constraint violation, I want to compare `message_id` from the array against a select statement from that table. If everything matches then this is an idempotent write and I can safely ignore the exception. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing the following: Using a CURSOR, iterating the rows that come back and append them to an array in a loop. Then, check that a) the length of _new_stream_messages is equal to what came back from the read, then b) that the contents of both are identical. I am certain there is a better way to do this but I haven't found it yet.

Code is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION __schema__.enforce_idempotent_append(
  _stream_id           CHAR(42),
  _start               INT,
  _check_length        BOOLEAN,
  _new_stream_messages __schema__.new_stream_message [])
  RETURNS VOID AS $F$
DECLARE
  _message_id_record RECORD;
  _message_id_cursor REFCURSOR;
  _message_ids       UUID [] = '{}' :: UUID [];
BEGIN
  _message_id_cursor = (
    SELECT *
    FROM __schema__.read(_stream_id, cardinality(_new_stream_messages), _start, true, false)
    OFFSET 1
  );

  FETCH FROM _message_id_cursor
  INTO _message_id_record;

  WHILE FOUND LOOP
    _message_ids = array_append(_message_ids, _message_id_record.message_id);

    FETCH FROM _message_id_cursor
    INTO _message_id_record;
  END LOOP;

  IF (_check_length AND cardinality(_new_stream_messages) > cardinality(_message_ids))
  THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'WrongExpectedVersion'
    USING HINT = 'Wrong message count';
  END IF;

  IF _message_ids <> (
    SELECT ARRAY(
        SELECT n.message_id
        FROM unnest(_new_stream_messages) n
    ))
  THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'WrongExpectedVersion';
  END IF;
END;
$F$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION idempotentAppend(streamId varchar, new_stream_message NewMessage[]) RETURNS AppendResult AS $$
DECLARE
    ...
BEGIN

    ...

    foreach message in ARRAY newMessages
    loop
        BEGIN
          INSERT INTO public.Messages (message_id, Type, JsonData, json_metadata)
          SELECT message.*;
        EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
            SELECT * FROM public.Messages into conflict WHERE public.Messages.Id = Id;
            IF message.type != conflict.type OR message.json_data != conflict.json_data THEN
                RAISE unique_violation USING MESSAGE = 'Duplicate message ID: ' || Id;
            END IF;
        END;
    end loop;

    ...

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As an aside, I found this in the #sql-stream-store channel in the ddd-cqrs-es slack and have been slowly working on a java version.

EDIT: Whelp...looks like I should have read more of the slack channel. Looks like you already solved it